# Parse Error on Input '<-' : Haskell

Tags: haskell, parse-error

I am taking input from the user and the code is as follows:

```
putStrLn $ "Enter number"
num <- getLine
main = print $ num
```

When I run this code, the compiler gives following error:

```
ra.hs:10:5: parse error on input `<-'
```

How can I remove this error? I have tried to use spaces, as well as tab characters, but the error persists. Please help.

Comment: Perhaps you should paste your entire code and try to format it properly: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to move all of your code into main

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Enter number"
    num <- getLine
    print num
```

The area outside of main is for declarations, etc.  You use `<-` inside of a `do`.

Also, you don't need the extra `$`'s when there is a single parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It just works for me, if I put lines to inside main.

```
main:: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn $ "Enter number"
    num <- getLine
    print $ num
```

Here is runnable code:
https://paiza.io/projects/CCc2kEbxXWfRRdVYAqbXww